# Is it possible to "favorite" a comment?

Tags: support, comments, bookmarks

Is it possible to "favorite" comments and have them shown in the user profile?
I know I can favorite a question, but sometimes, comments reveal a great piece of information too and it'd be great to favorite comments as well.

Answer (score 2):

No. You also can't "favorite" answers. It's a question-only thing... so if you have a comment or answer you wish to remember, then mark the parent question.

Comment: You can "favourite" an answer by bookmarking it's permalink yourself - but that's external to the site.

Comment: @ChrisF: Good suggestion - belongs in the FAQ! :)