# Could the favourites mechanism be extended to include comments?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, bookmarks

I've seen a similar thread for [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2588/188293) and a question concerning the very feature I mean in [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32752/is-it-possible-to-favorite-a-comment) but no actual suggestion. I decided to post one in order to see if other users agree that such a feature would be of use and also to find out if it would be technically feasible (requiring a sane amount of code modification).

Among the comments on Stack Overflow (and other SE sites), there are some genuine gems. Be it a piece of advice, a suggestion or just a hilarious remark, a comment is sometimes worth returning to.

While I know how to bookmark the comments in my browser, I find this pretty annoying while switching computers (it's hard to keep sync between different browsers). I'd like to keep them in one place, preferably in my SO profile.

Personally, I'd love and use a feature like this. What do you think about it?

Comment: Given that the life-time of comments is not guaranteed, would it not be better to copy them somewhere? A Google doc or whatever?

Comment: @Bart: Question lifetimes are also never guaranteed.

Comment: @Purmou More so than comments though. And comments are usually small enough to simply copy/paste to a document.

Comment: @Bart I occasionally do that, but it's troublesome. A one-click solution would be amazing. Even if temporary, it could be treated as a scratchpad, from which to copy the comments when there's more time for that.

Comment: Deleted comments cannot be seen, deleted questions can.

Comment: @casperOne it doesn't defeat the purpose though. I bookmark them in my browser from time to time and they're just as likely to disappear as they would be in my profile.

Comment: What's the point to having favourite comments? The point with questions is that you get notified if they change (and get new comments and answers) - comments do not change (after the first 5 minutes).

Comment: @Oded the point is to have the links to them saved in one place. Or possibly to display some comments you find good in your profile, similarly to the stars in chat.

Comment: @Oded Well, technically moderators can edit any comment past the first 5 minutes, but that's extremely rare (if I remember correctly I've only done it once, to fix a link in a great comment). That said, I can't think of any good reason I'd want to favourite a comment, Tom.

Comment: *" Question lifetimes are also never guaranteed."* If they live long enough to get included in a data dump they are forever. Answers, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I really hope not.

Comments are second-class citizens; they only exist to provide clarification for a post, and are not guaranteed to be permanent.  They don't have any other sanctioned purpose.

We already get enough angst from people proclaiming `ZOMG WHY U DELETE COMMENTS?` so I'd rather not see anything attached to them that might provide them with unwarranted legitimacy.

Comment: Thanks for your input. This is indeed a valid argument.